# Implementing a customized drawable in Android

Tags: android

I was trying to get hold of 2D graphics in Android.
  As a example i want to implement a custom drawable and show it in my Activity

I have defined a customized drawable by extending from Android drawable as mentioned below

```
 class myDrawable extends Drawable {

   private static final String TAG = myDrawable.class.getSimpleName();
   private ColorFilter cf;
   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {


     //First you define a colour for the outline of your rectangle

     Paint rectanglePaint = new Paint();
     rectanglePaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
     rectanglePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
     rectanglePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

     //Then create yourself a Rectangle
     RectF rectangle = new RectF(15.0f, 50.0f, 55.0f, 75.0f); //in pixels


     Log.d(TAG,"On Draw method");
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Paint paintHandl = new Paint();
     //  paintHandl.setColor(0xaabbcc);
     paintHandl.setARGB(125, 234, 213, 34 );
     RectF rectObj = new RectF(5,5,25,25);
     canvas.drawRoundRect(rectangle, 0.5f, 0.5f, rectanglePaint);

   }

   @Override
   public int getOpacity() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return 100;
   }

   @Override
   public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     this.cf = cf;
   }
 }
```

I am trying to get this displayed in my activity, as shown below

```
public class custDrawable extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


 LinearLayout layObj = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        layObj = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLay);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        myDrawable myDrawObj = new myDrawable();
        imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawObj);
        imageView.invalidate();
//  layObj.addView(myDrawObj, params);

    }
}
```

But when i run the app i see no rectangle on the activity, can anyone help me out?
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is in the `getOpacity()` method.  100 is not a valid value.  You should use a [PixelFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html) value.  Also, you should create your `RectF` and `Paint` in the constructor and then just adjust the values in `draw()` so you don't create so many objects that need garbage collected.  Like this:

```
public class Square extends Drawable
{
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRect;

    public Square()
    {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mRect = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // Set the correct values in the Paint
        mPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        // Adjust the rect
        mRect.left = 15.0f;
        mRect.top = 50.0f;
        mRect.right = 55.0f;
        mRect.bottom = 75.0f;

        // Draw it
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, 0.5f, 0.5f, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity()
    {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter arg0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the changes mentioned by casey, but still i am not able to see any valid stuff drawn on my view.

Comment: Nother problem is that it seems that you never add the `ImageView` to your `LinearLayout`.  You need to add `layObj.addView(imageView);` to the end of `onCreate()`

Comment: I have added the imageView to linear layout, it is basically a problem with set bounds
In xml , i hardcoded the width and height of the image view, now it is showing up, so some problem with my setBounds is it?

Comment: Is it possible to embed an image with in the rounded rectangle or any primitive shape i draw, say polygon or a path? If so can you please share the code?

Comment: If you override the `draw()` method you can draw whatever you want to the `Canvas`.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to set the paint properties in the `draw()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to implement other overrides like `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight`. One way to tell is that you set your layout_width and `layout_height` to some constant (`layout_width="42dip"` `layout_height="42dip"` in XML or setting your `layoutParams` to some value if you are using Java layouts). Some `View` types handle not having `getIntrinsic*` implemented than others, so try them! This includes a straight `View`.

You can try returning -1 if there's no specific width or height.

Hard to tell if the issue ever got resolved, but I got here via Google trying to help myself remember the details of making a custom `Drawable`, plus I want to help people avoid this: http://xkcd.com/979/