# How to implement dynamic values on menu item in Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu item in the action bar. Along with the menu item image, I need to show some number associated with it which will change often.  I am not using Action bar sherlock. I don't want to use that. Other than this everything else just works fine. In the shown image, the white icon color icon is mine. I need to generate the number with the red color background dynamically. How can I do that in Android?

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Update:

I have this menu item in my menu.xml. This should work like a notification menu item which shows the number of notification count. I set the menu icon like,

```
 menuItem.setIcon(image);
```

Now, on top of the menu item I need to place one text view which has the total count of notifications.

is it possible to implement this functionality with viewbadger?
[Github url](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered how to add an actionView to a menu item and retrieve as set values to the view in code.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648170/857681

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of trying of nearly all resources on SO I turned to blogs; succesfully. I want to share what worked for me (Api >= 13); [source](http://www.jmhend.me/layerdrawable-menuitems).

Let's start with the sweet code, **the way it's used**:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //inflate menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);

    // Get the notifications MenuItem and LayerDrawable (layer-list)
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();

    // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable
    Utils2.setBadgeCount(this, icon, 2);

    return true;
}
```

The `menu_my.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_notifications"
        android:title="Notifications"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

This class that conveniently makes a `BadgeDrawable`; its appearance can be modified as well:

```
public class BadgeDrawable extends Drawable {

    private float mTextSize;
    private Paint mBadgePaint;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

    private String mCount = "";
    private boolean mWillDraw = false;

    public BadgeDrawable(Context context) {
        //mTextSize = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.badge_text_size);
        mTextSize = 12F;

        mBadgePaint = new Paint();
        mBadgePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mBadgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBadgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!mWillDraw) {
            return;
        }

        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

        // Position the badge in the top-right quadrant of the icon.
        float radius = ((Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 1) / 2;
        float centerX = width - radius - 1;
        float centerY = radius + 1;

        // Draw badge circle.
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mBadgePaint);

        // Draw badge count text inside the circle.
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.length(), mTxtRect);
        float textHeight = mTxtRect.bottom - mTxtRect.top;
        float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
        canvas.drawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    }

    /*
    Sets the count (i.e notifications) to display.
     */
    public void setCount(int count) {
        mCount = Integer.toString(count);

        // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
        mWillDraw = count > 0;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

This class that helps to set the number. I recommend implementing even more thods to set badge as date, etc:

```
public class Utils2 {
    public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, int count) {

        BadgeDrawable badge;

        // Reuse drawable if possible
        Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
        if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
            badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
        } else {
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        }

        badge.setCount(count);
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
    }


}
```

And *mui importante* a drawable (like a layout) in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_notification"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ice_skate"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ice_skate" />
</layer-list>
```

Good lucks!

Comment: Is your ic_menu_notifications is layer list file you have mentioned in the bottom?

Comment: You just copied the code from the source. Please stop doing that.

Comment: @Ravi, that is not what had I done; the source link doesn't even work anymore; and I can assure you this code was in production on my app before I posted it here; it's important to explain how this 5 blocks of code work as well.

Comment: Link is not working.

Comment: @PratikButani, true; that's why I pasted in the snippets.

Comment: I was getting ClassCastException for conversion from BitmapDrawable to LayerDrawable. follow this for this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386027/java-lang-classcastexception-android-graphics-drawable-bitmapdrawable-cannot-be

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing you can try:

Create a custom `Drawable` that paint you image in the background and text on top of the image. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967904/implementing-a-customized-drawable-in-android) for sample.

Then set this `Drawable` as the `MenuItem` background dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Use action view. It works with both: default `ActionBar` and `ActionBarSherlock`.

[Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)

With this approach you can just create your own `View` (by inflating some layout for example) and then do whatever you want (change background, change content, add another views dynamically if your action view is subclass of `ViewGroup` etc.).