# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

Tags: android, android-studio

error is generated on these code : 
setBadgeCount(this,icon ,"0");

here is my code:

```
  MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();

    // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable

    setBadgeCount(this,icon ,"0");
```

Comment: itemCart.getIcon() returns BitmapDrawable, not LayerDrawable

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to refer to `icon` by interface `Drawable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `ClassCastException` because your `MenuItem` returns not `BitmapDrawable`, you can create `LayerDrawable` from `BitmapDrawable` you get from `MenuItem`

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138871/4142087), or official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) you can do it this way:

```
BitmapDrawable iconBitmap = (BitmapDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
LayerDrawable iconLayer = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable [] { iconBitmap });
setBadgeCount(this, iconLayer, "0");
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException is generated .. what should i do?

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
 MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        BitmapDrawable iconBitmap = (BitmapDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
        LayerDrawable iconLayer = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable [] { iconBitmap });
      setBadgeCount(MainActivity.this, iconLayer, "9");
      return true;
}

Comment: public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {
        BadgeDrawable badge;
        Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge); 
        if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
            badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
        }
        else {
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        }
        badge.setCount(count);
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
    }

Comment: @JaydeepJoshi You forgot this : **getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);**

Answer (score 1):

Change the menu items icon drawable from vector drawable to layer-list. In the layer list you can include the vector items like this. Here the cart icon is a vector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cart_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cart_icon" />
</layer-list>
```